# Accessing @Bean method from configuration directly

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a configuration class which has some beans defined. Can I access the bean method from a service directly like below?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{
   @Bean
   public Sample sample(int x){
       return new Sample(x);
   }
}

@Service
public class MyService{
     @Autowired
     MyConfig config;

     public void test(){
         Sample sample = config.sample(2);
     }
}
```

Comment: Then why do you use `@Bean` if it is not managed (so it is not `@Bean` at all)?

Comment: I would like a managed bean. The only way I can do that is to get it from app context?

Comment: But you dont want it as managed since you want to get it from different bean

Comment: Is there no way without @autowiring to get Sample object in Myservice?

Comment: how about new Sample(whatever) ?

Comment: I can but I want a spring managed bean. How do I create a spring managed bean in my service if my bean method is parameterized?

Comment: You cannot - thats the thing. The only paramenter that can be used is another managed bean - so you can indeed inject another bean or `@Value` but thats it. No runime injections.

Comment: Can you tell us why it's parameterized, or how do you intend to use the parameter? Perhaps that can help us with what you're trying to achieve, and so we can help you with an alternative. The current idea is pretty difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `BeanFactory` interface (`ApplicationContext` implements it) and the *prototype* scope of the required bean.

In `MyConfig` class, the scope of the bean should be set to "prototype":

```
// import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Sample sample(int x) {
  return new Sample(x);
}
```

Then, instead of autowiring `config` in `MyService`, an instance of `BeanFactory` should be plugged:

```
@Autowired
private BeanFactory beanFactory;
```

To obtain an instance of `Sample` bean, it should be called as follows:

```
Sample sample = beanFactory.getBean(Sample.class, 1);
```

Comment: if I call it just like a method from MyService class, like config.sample(2), would it not be a spring managed bean?